# Time complexity and recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I'm having difficulty understanding how to develop recurrence relations. The code I'm given is

```
 int result = bizarre(n, n);
 public static int bizarre (int first, int second)
 {
   if (second <= 1)
   {
     int temp = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < first; i++)
         temp += i;
     return temp;
   }
   return bizarre (first, second-1);
 }
```

From what I'm understanding is that

```
T(n) = n + 1
T(1) = 1
```

but that doesn't seem right. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the reasons you’re having trouble here is that there are two independent parameters to the function, so your recurrence relation will need to have two different arguments to account for this.

In the case where your second argument is 0 or 1, you do work proportional to the first argument. You could write this as

> T(m, 1) = Θ(m).

Otherwise, the function does a constant amount of work and then makes a recursive call on the same first input and a decremented second input. Here’s what this looks like:

> T(m, n) = T(m, n - 1) + O(1).

Do you think you can solve things from there?

Comment: Yeah, the two parameters did confuse me and I wasn't sure on whether or not writing a relation like this would work. I understand how you got the recurring case but could you explain the base case? I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Also, how would you go about obtaining the time complexity? I haven't worked on any similar questions so I apologize if this should be simple to me.

Comment: In the base case, you just have a loop that runs `first` times, doing O(1) work each. I've denoted your first parameter with *m*, so the work done is O(m).

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. One last question that gave me some confusion was the first line where the parameters for bizarre are both 'n', would this not mean that first and second are the same values leading the base case to be T(1,1) = O(1) ?

Comment: Think about what the first recursive call is going to look like if you call this function as `bizarre(n, n)`. What will each argument be?

Comment: Wouldn't it return (n, n-1)? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Right, that's the next recursive call. So notice that just because the initial arguments are n and n, the next set of arguments won't necessarily be n and n. You won't drop to T(1, 1) if you start with T(n, n) (unless n = 1).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the recurrence relation is given by

```
T(n) = no. of subproblems generated at each step * T(size of each subproblem) + complexity of the divide/conquer step
```

and

```
T(1) = complexity of base case(s)
```

In your example, the variable "second" is getting smaller by 1 at each recursive call. Also, the number of subproblems you create at every step is just one, since you're only calling the method once.

The code doesn't really do any work at each recursive step except for a comparison, so that's an O(1) operation.

So,

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(1)
```

Finally, T(1) is what happens at the base case, which is a summation of n numbers.

```
T(1) = O(n)
```